# unity c# linq firsordefault

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Please explain this line of code. I'm newbie and I  can't get it
what does this mean: `(dir => IsDirection(currentSwipe, dir.Value))`

```
var swipeDir = cardinalDirections.FirstOrDefault(dir => IsDirection(currentSwipe, dir.Value));
```

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/swipe-in-all-directions-touch-and-mouse.165416/page-2#post-2741253

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) (default usually `null`) object in your `cardinalDirections` collection where the function `IsDirection` (which returns a bool) with the parameters `currentSwipe` and the item from the collection returns true.

Think of `dir =>` as declaring a variable `dir` for each object in the collection and then you're doing something with it.  For instance, `dir => dir.value == 'somevalue'` would also be correct.

If there are two or more objects that meet the criteria, you'll get the first object in the collection.  If there are no objects that meet the criteria, you'll get the default value (`null` as mentioned above).

To be more familiar with the syntax, please read about [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) as provided by **@BviLLe_Kid**.